# Conditional custom redirect

Tags: plugins, javascript, redirect, advanced-custom-fields

I want to achieve the following:

- On a post or a page, I can define an optional custom redirect URL (possibly as an Advanced Custom Field)
- If I view this post/page with a specific added URL parameter (like "?redirect=true", send a redirect to the defined custom URL, otherwise do not redirect.

My naive approach would be to add this as a javascript to the post/page template.

Is there a better option? Or a plugin I could (ab)use for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be tough. As you suggested you can use ACF to add a custom field in post/page and then use the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook to check if the current page's custom field is a valid URL as well as $_GET['redirect'] is true, wp_redirect to that URL.

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    if( is_url(GET_ACF_FIELD_VALUE( 'CUSTOM_FIELD' )) && !empty($_GET['redirect']) && $_GET['redirect'] == 'true)
    {
        wp_redirect( GET_ACF_FIELD_VALUE( 'CUSTOM_FIELD' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thanks! As I'm a WP noob (from a customization point of view) - where do I need to put this?

Comment: You need to have little bit knowledge for such customizations. Above code has a template function "GET_ACF_FIELD_VALUE( 'CUSTOM_FIELD' )" which is supposed to be replaced with respect to your implementation of custom field. Above code should be pasted in your theme's functions.php